# Given that f(n) = 10000000n and g(n) = n^2. Why f(n) is O(g(n))?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm trying to solve the following problem but am unsure on the explanation given in the solution. f2(n) appears to be O(n) and f4(n) appears to be O(n^2). Why, then, does f2(n) is O(f4(n))?

[image: Question]

[image: Answer]

Comment: Sorry, but links to external sites are bad, because they're not stable. Also, what is "MIT question"? Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You should write that f2 is **in** O(f4), not that f2=O(f4), since f2 is one function, while O(f4) is a set of many functions. The proposition f_2 is in O(f_4) is correct  because |f_2(n)| <= 1*|f_4(n)| for large enough values of n, which is the condition that a function f2 must satisfy to be in the set O(f4).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Linking to critical information off site is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Read the wikipedia page about Big O notation and you will understand it better. 
Informally, a description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function.

Given that f(n) = 10000000n and g(n) = n², when you say that **f(n) is O(g(n)**), it means there exists c > 0 (e.g., c = 1) and n0 such that f(n) ≤ cg(n) whenever n ≥ n0.

If f2 is O(f4) it means that f2 grows asymptotically slower than f4.

Answer (score 0):

Your current statement is not true. A contradiction example is `f2(n) = n = O(n)` and `f4(n) = 1 = O(n^2)`. But, `f2(n)` is not `O(f4(n))`.

However, as mentioned in the answer that `f4(n)` is quadratic and `f2(n)` is linear, by the definition of the `big-Oh` symbol, we can say `f2(n) = O(f4(n))`.

Comment: If you use this argument then f2(n) is also O(n^2). In addition the question says that f2 is O(f4) cause f4 in this example is n^2. It doesn't say that f2 is O(f4) cause f4 is O(n^2).

Comment: @DiegoMarin I know! But SO didn't mention that `f4(n)` is `n^2`! He said `f4(n)` is in `O(n^2)`. Hence, as I explained, the conclusion is not true.

Comment: The solution says "The function f2(n) is linear, while the function f4(n) is quadratic, so f2(n) is O(f4(n)).". It seems he is confused cause a function which is O(n) is also O(n^2).

Comment: @DiegoMarin Ok. You're right. I've just seen the link to the answer and question! Indeed, I answered the question of SO that is written in the post.